# How do I install bundle to sling whilst building a docker image

Tags: dockerfile, sling

My goal is to setup a sling project installed to a docker image ready for use. I can do all of these steps manually, but putting it together for a CI build is proving difficult.

If I was using tomcat, in the dockerfile I'd simply copy a war to the install folder and it'll install when the container first starts.

I haven't been able to find a similar 'install' folder that comes with the OOTB version of sling. [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/installing-and-upgrading-bundles.html) says I need to use HTTP to do the install. This is an issue as it requires that I start Sling whilst building the docker image, but if I do this the image will never finish building.

I'm trying to write a single line of bash to do the following

- start sling
- test if it's started using curl
- use curl to install the bundle *(not yet written)*

My Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
COPY /maven/org.apache.sling.launchpad-8.jar /opt/sling/
COPY /maven/custombundle.jar /opt/sling/sling/installerfolder

WORKDIR /opt/sling/
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /opt/sling/sling

RUN java $JAVA_OPTS -jar org.apache.sling.launchpad-8.jar $SLING_OPTS & ; until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:8080/index.html); do sleep 5 ; done ; #TODO install bundle
#Docker will snapshot the image here
```

The issue I get is a "returned a non-zero"

```
 The command '/bin/sh -c java $JAVA_OPTS -jar org.apache.sling.launchpad-8.jar $SLING_OPTS & ; until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:8080/index.html); do ; sleep 5 ; done' returned a non-zero code: 2 -> [Help 1]
```

You can see my full project here:
https://bitbucket.org/rickardstech/hawksite/src

Answer (score 1):

It exists a solution using file installer provider :
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/file-installer-provider.html

Just configure and copy bundle in the directory